# Azure Pipelines - Equivalent Az DevOps Commands Required

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have successfully used the below commands to update our Azure DevOps project wiki in Powershell ISE.

```
$etagVar = (az devops wiki page show --org https://dev.azure.com/[MyOrg] --project [MyProjectName] --path '/MyWiki/HelloWorld' --wiki [MyWiki_wiki] --query eTag -o tsv)

az devops wiki page update --path 'MyWikiPath/HelloWorld' --wiki [MyWiki_wiki --content "Yessssss, it worked !!!" --version $etagVar
```

I now need to incorporate these two commands into a YAML Azure Pipeline. I am not particularly bothered whether this is done using Bash, PowerShell, Windows Batch Script or any Azure pipeline Task for that matter. As long as it works, I have no qualms at all.

So far, I've tried a Bash task and it's been hugely unsuccessful. Any suggestions or ideas would therefore be most appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error you see while using the bash task? Please include your YAML snippet as well in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get my Pipeline to update a Wiki using the [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops). Here is my working YAML definition:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- bash: az devops configure --defaults organization=$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) project=$(System.TeamProject) --use-git-aliases true
  displayName: 'Set default Azure DevOps organization and project'

- bash: |
    eTag=$(az devops wiki page show --wiki project.wiki --path '/MyWiki' --query eTag -o tsv)
    az devops wiki page update --wiki project.wiki --path '/MyWiki' --content "Hello World!" --version $eTag
  displayName: 'Update Wiki'
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

As for the auth, you can authenticate using the [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops#systemaccesstoken) security token used by the running pipeline, by assigning it to an environment variable named `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT`, as shown in the snippet above. For other examples, check this article: [Azure DevOps CLI in Azure Pipeline YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/azure-devops-cli-in-yaml?view=azure-devops)

**Note:** You may have to tweak your [pipeline permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58350802/10805761) a bit to let it update the Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

You just run it with PowerShell like your run it in your PC, you just need to authenticate (with the `env`):

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $etagVar = (az devops wiki page show --org https://dev.azure.com/shaykia --project GitSample --path '/README' --wiki 1 --query eTag -o tsv)
      az devops wiki page update --path 'MyWikiPath/HelloWorld' --wiki [MyWiki_wiki --content "Yessssss, it worked !!!" --version $etagVar
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shayki Abramczyk. Looks like we were both thinking along the same lines eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

That's excellent @Bhargavi Annadevara. On the back of my last post yesterday, I pondered briefly and realised that I'd perhaps even answered my own question by stating *"......I am not particularly bothered whether this is done using Bash, Powershell, Windows Batch Script"*

That's because I very quickly managed to revise my existing commands and implemented it with a Pipeline Powershell task (below) which achieved my objective.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
 inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: |
     # Write your PowerShell commands here.
           
     $etagVar = (az devops wiki page show --org https://dev.azure.com/[OrgName] --project [TeamProjectName] --path '/[TeamProjectWiki_Path]' --wiki [WikiName] --query eTag -o tsv)
     az devops wiki page update --path '[TeamProjectWiki_Path]' --wiki [WikiName] --content "Hello World....!!" --version $etagVar --verbose
 displayName: 'Preparing to update the wiki page'
 env:
   AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
```

It's good that we at least have two working options to go with. Will try your Bash implementation too by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, glad that helps! There's not a lot of difference in implementation for both, feel free to choose what suits your requirement the best. :)